# What is the meaning of hot wire in AC?

Tags: electricity

I'm currently learning the basics of electricity, and there's something I don't quite understand. From what I'm getting, in DC - Direct current - such as in batteries, electricity flows in one direction - from the (-) pole to the (+) pole. But with AC, electrons flow back and forth to both directions. So, what is the meaning of the hot wire versus the neutral wire in, say, a home electricity system? If so that with AC electrons flow back and forth to both directions, what is the difference between them?

Comment: Wiring configurations are often different in different countries.  Do you live in the U.S.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In household AC, it's not like one wire being at a voltage of $+V$, then that wire going to $0$ while the other wire is going to $+V$. Rather, one wire will be (more or less) constantly at $0\,\text{V}$, while the other one will oscillate between the electrical potentials $+V$ and $-V$. So the one with the varying voltage on it is the live or "hot" wire, because most of the time its voltage is different from ground, whereas the neutral wire will always have (close to) ground potential, if correctly wired.

Comment: Can one only get zapped only by touching the hot wire? or either one of them?

Comment: If the household load is reasonably balanced, you can only get zapped by the hot wire, yes. This is also the reason why e.g. on a light switch you should interrupt the live wire, not the neutral, otherwise you can get zapped by touching the bulb socket. I still recommend you **do not** try this. Errors happen, and the load is not always balanced, so the neutral wire can still have some voltage on it.

Comment: when you say that "one wire will be constantly at 0 V" - you mean 0 volts with respect to what?

Comment: That's referring to ground potential.

Comment: what causes it to be ground potential? Is ground just an object with neutral charge? are all the everyday objects we use are at ground potential also?

Comment: What's causing it to be ground potential is the fact that after going through protection measures (GFCI/RCD) it is usually wired to the ground. Everything that is *grounded* is at ground potential.